# Value of field based on other value field in New Form SharePoint

Tags: web-part, javascript

[image: the picture]

Here in the picture you can see how it looks like.
I want when in `1 Variable Daten` is **empty** then `1 Anzahl Stunden` and `2 Variable Daten` to be empty.

Comment: Field "1 Anzahl Stunden" is free text? Or with fixed value ?

Comment: It is free text

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some javascript/jQuery code to accomplish this. Commonly adding a content editor to the page and pointing to a js file somewhere in the site, most commonly site assets library, will make it happen.

Comment: Can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually solved with JavaScript and CEWP. One possible solution is to hide one field based on the value of other. Two links about that:

[Hide column in SharePoint custom list based on values](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252468/Hide-column-in-SharePoint-custom-list-based-on-val)

[Ocultar columnas en base al valor de otra columna en SharePoint](http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/ocultar-columnas-en-base-al-valor-de.html)

Hope it will be helpfully!

Comment: Can you help me with chaging value Script?
_Thank you!_

Comment: Wiche type of value do you wante to change? Text, Lookup, choice?

Comment: I want when *1 Variable Daten* is *Empty* then *1 Anzahl Stunden* and *2 Variable Daten* to be *Empty*

Comment: But what type of sharepoint field are?